# uitabbarcontroller get NSString from the uitabbarcontroller class

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a uitabbarcontroller in my project and i pass to him data (to NSString),
And i want to get this data from my tabs controllers,

how i do this?

tnx!

Comment: sorry but could you elaborate on what you want the uitabbarcontroller to do exactly?

Comment: I have 2 tabs in my uitabbarcontroller and i want to get variables from my uitabbarcontroller class. (in my views are in tab bar)

Comment: Get properties from my uitabbarcontroller class (.h file and .m file)

Comment: I have answered almost the exact question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15611879/1075405)!